# If $(-\Delta_x)^{-1}f(x,t)$ is jointly continuous in $(x,t)$, then is $t \to \int \lvert f(x,t) \rvert^2 dx$ also continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The question is summarized in the title.

More precisely, let $f(x,t) \in L^2\bigl([0,1]^2 \times [0,1] \bigr)$ with $\int_{[0,1]^2} f(x,t) d^2x=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Then, we can apply the inverse Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{-1}_x$ to this $f(x,t)$ to see that
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{-1}_xf(x,t) \in H^2_xL^2_t ([0,1]^2 \times [0,1] \bigr)
\end{equation}
That is, $\int_0^1 \lVert (-\Delta)^{-1}f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{H^2_x}^2 dt < \infty$.

Now, let us further assume that $(-\Delta)^{-1}_xf(x,t)$ is in fact $\textit{jointly}$ continuous with respect to $(x,t)$ on $[0,1]^2 \times [0,1]$.

Then, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
\lVert f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2= \int_{[0,1]^2} \lvert f(x,t) \rvert^2 d^2x
\end{equation}
is still continuous as a function of $t \in [0,1]$.

Since, $x$ and $t$ are independent variables, I guess the answer would be yes, but I cannot justify it. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Here is a counterexample on the spatial domain $[0,1]$, it can be easily extended to $[0,1]^2$.
Define
$$
f_n(x) := \sin( n \pi x ).
$$
Then $\|f_n\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 = \frac12$, $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$, and $f_n \not \to 0$ in $L^2(0,1)$.
For $t\in [\frac1{n+1}, \frac1n]$ define
$$
f(t,x) = \lambda f_n(x) + (1-\lambda) f_{n+1}(x),
$$
where $\lambda\in [0,1]$ is that
$$
t = \lambda \frac1n + (1-\lambda) \frac1{n+1}.
$$
Set $f(0,x)=0$.
Then $t \mapsto f(\cdot,t)$ is continuous for $t>0$, but the limit $\lim_{t\searrow0} f(\cdot,t)$ does not exist in $L^2(0,1)$.
(The map $t\mapsto \lambda\mapsto f$ is continuous. And $f(\cdot, \frac1n) = f_n$.)
Moreover, since $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ are orthogonal, $\|f(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2}^2 \ge \frac14$ for all $t>0$, so that $t\mapsto \|f(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2}^2$ is not continuous at $t=0$.

Now $(-\Delta_x)^{-1}f$ is (assuming homogeneous boundary conditions)
$$\begin{split}
(-\Delta_x)^{-1}f(t,\cdot) &= \lambda (-\Delta_x)^{-1} f_n + (1-\lambda) (-\Delta_x)^{-1}f_{n+1}\\
&= \lambda \frac1{n^2\pi^2}f_n + \lambda \frac1{(n+1)^2\pi^2}f_{n+1}
\end{split},
$$
which is continuous at $t=0$, i.e., $(-\Delta_x)^{-1}f(\cdot,0) \to 0$ for $t\to 0$.

---

For spatial domain $[0,1]^d$, $d>1$, define
$$
f_n(x) := \prod_{k=1}^d \sin( n \pi x_k ).
$$
And the same reasoning as above applies. The example can also be modified for different boundary conditions: set $f_n$ the be the $n$-th eigenfunction of $-\Delta$.

Comment: Is this the right counterexample? $f$ must belong to $L^2\bigl( [0,1] \times [0,1] \bigr)$. Also, I would like to know continuity of $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert^2_{L^2_x}$.

Comment: I can see that your $f$ belongs to $L^2\bigl([0,1] \times [0,1] \bigr)$. However, it seems that continuity of $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert^2_{L^2_x}$ has not been contradicted.

Comment: If we set $f$ to zero at $t=0$, then this expression is not continuous at zero.

Comment: With the choice $f(t) = \sqrt\lambda f_n + \sqrt{1-\lambda} f_{n+1}$ the $L^2_x$ norm is constant for $t>0$.

Comment: I see. So, it is more like the issue of defining $f(x,0)$ for continuity... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps, at least is it possible to show that $t \to \lVert f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$ is "bounded" for $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: If this needs another full answer, I will post another question.

Comment: $t\mapsto \|f(t)\|_{L^2_x}^2$ is bounded, it attains values in $[1/4,1/2]$.

Comment: I mean, in general case. Perhaps could you answer here? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451053/if-delta-x-1fx-t-is-jointly-continuous-in-x-t-then-is-t-to-in

Comment: The answer to the other question is also: NO. Just define $f(t):= \lambda n f_n + (1-\lambda)(n+1)f_{n+1}$.

Comment: I don't think your new example is in $L^2$ jointly in $x$ and $t$.